How to use multiple middlewares with NextAuth and i18n in Nextjs
I had NextAuth working well with the default middleware from NexAuth, but now that I added a middleware from i18n i don't know how to combine them.
The middleware from i18n is working, but nextAuth middleware is not.
The code before i18n middleware (it was working well)
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: [ "/practice/overview" ],
};

Then I added the i18n middleware, and NextAuth middleware stopped working:
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { i18nRouter } from "next-i18n-router";
import i18nConfig from "./i18nConfig";

export function middleware(request) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/practice/overview",
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next).*)",
  ],
};

I also tried to implement withAuth, but is not working:
import { i18nRouter } from "next-i18n-router";
import i18nConfig from "./i18nConfig";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth(
  // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
  function middleware(req) {
    console.log(req.nextauth.token);
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
      error: "/error",
    },
  }
);

export function middleware(request) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/practice/overview",
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next).*)",
  ],
};

How can I chain them or call them simultaneous ?
